# Learning Wemake-Python-Styleguide: Why do I receive a magic number violation for keyword arguments?

Tags: python-3.x, wemake-python-style-guide

I keep receiving the following error

```
WPS432 Found magic number: 50
```

for a function below:

```
from brain_games.evenodd_game import oe_func


def main():
    """Play even-odd game.

    Returns:
        game playground.
    """
    print('Welcome to the Brain Games!')
    return oe_func(min_val=1, max_val=50)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

According to WPS, keyword arguments inside a function are excluded from the magic number check (see link below). Since `max_val=50` is a keyword argument, why do I receive the above error?

https://wemake-python-stylegui.de/en/latest/pages/usage/violations/best_practices.html